# How to specify JSON Schema if array is not required when there are no items in it?

Tags: json, jsonschema

Say I have some json data like this:

```
{
    "quantity": 3,
    "modifiers": [{}]
}
```

I do not want `modifiers` to be present if there is no intent of adding objects into `modifiers`.

This should be the correct way if there are no `modifiers`:

```
{
    "quantity": 3,
}
```

and this should be correct with `modifiers`:

```
{
    "quantity": 3,
    "modifiers": [{
        "testing": "some data here"
    }]
}
```

How would I structure the JSON Schema to validate the above-most example to be incorrect?

edit:
Example of JSON Schema for the above examples:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "quantity": {
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 1
        },
        "modifiers": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "testing": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "minItems": 1
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "quantity"
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is the language ? Node js ?

Comment: JSON Schema. My bad, will edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: show us at least quantity validator

Comment: Are you constrained by a specific JSON Schema draft version?

Comment: Done, I have updated question with sample schema based on the given examples.

Comment: No constraints, since I am just starting out, the newer the better!

Comment: I can't draw up and test a schema right now, but have a look at [conditional schema applicability](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.6) keywords found in the current validation spec.

Comment: Thanks, I took a look and also at some examples online but couldn't find a way to `not required` a property. This is my initial intuition for the if condition: `"if": { "properties": { "modifiers": { "minItems": 0, "maxItems": 0 } } },
                    "then": { "need a way to set not required": [ "modifiers" ] }`

Comment: I think I got it: `,
  "if": {
    "required": [
      "modifiers"
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "modifiers": {
        "minItems": 1
      }
    }
  }` Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

(Draft 7 only) To *not* allow an array to be empty if present, do this:

```
  "if": {
    "required": [
      "modifiers"
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "modifiers": {
        "minItems": 1
      }
    }
  }
```

This will ensure that this is invalid:

```
{
    "quantity" : 1,
      "modifiers":[]
}
```

However note that the following json would be valid:

```
{
    "quantity" : 1,
      "modifiers":[{}]
}
```

If you don't want that, then make sure to include the appropriate `required` field. This would be how the final schema look like based on the given example/schema above:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "quantity": {
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 1
    },
    "modifiers": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "testing": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "testing"
        ]
      },
      "minItems": 1
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "quantity"
  ],
  "if": {
    "required": [
      "modifiers"
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "modifiers": {
        "minItems": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, this would also be invalid:

```
{
    "quantity" : 1,
      "modifiers":[{}]
}
```

And this would be valid:

```
{
    "quantity" : 1,
      "modifiers":[{"testing":"343"}]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're only missing one thing. Just add `"minProperties": 1` at `/properties/modifiers/items`.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "quantity": {
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 1
        },
        "modifiers": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "testing": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "minProperties": 1
            },
            "minItems": 1
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "quantity"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Oh nice! This works great too, simple and clean, thank you!